# Cannot get program to recognize capital letters when input?

Tags: java

Java beginner here - hoping someone can help me solve this problem. I am trying to write a simple program that will display a particular message depending on the character entered by the user. The problem I'm having is that it won't recognize the validity of capitalized characters in determining which message to print.

The code compiles OK but if I enter a capital letter, it prints out the message telling me it is not a valid character to start an identifier.

Here is a snippet of the source code:

```
choice2 = (char) System.in.read();

if(choice2 == 'q')
   break;

else 
  if(choice2 == '_' || choice2 >= 'a' && choice2 <= 'z' && choice2 >= 'A' && choice2 <= 'Z' && choice2 > '0' && choice2 <= '9')
    System.out.println("That is a valid character to start an identifier.");

else 
  if(choice2 == '$')
    System.out.println("That is a valid character to start an identifier but should only be used by mechanically generated source code");

else
  System.out.println("Sorry, that is not a valid character to start an identifier");
break;
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is it something inherent to the char data type?

Thanks

Comment: You have all those `&&` so it must meet all those conditions. So when you enter in an A it will be false because it does not satisfy all the && statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your boolean groupings and a couple `&&` should be `||`

```
if (choice2 == '_' || 
    ((choice2 >= 'a' && choice2 <= 'z') || 
     (choice2 >= 'A' && choice2 <= 'Z') || 
     (choice2 > '0' && choice2 <= '9')))
```

This will evaluate to `true` if `choice2 == '_'` OR if `choice2` is either between `a` and `z` inclusive, between `A` and `Z` inclusive, or between `0` and `9` inclusive.